# What is the difference between const {document} = this.props and ({document} = this.props)

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between `const {document} = this.props` and `({document} = this.props)`? I am using `const {document} = this.props` in a lot of cases and I wonder if it will be bad on the apps performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* document key from this.props is stored in const document
   & it called destructing object ( introduced in es6 ) */

   const {document} = this.props;
```

whereas ({document} = this.props) returns object with key document which is mutable. Means if you change document value later, it will reflect in this.props too ( not recommended ).

Comment: Okay. Do you happen to know the impact a const has on an apps performance? I am wondering because I am creating lots of items in a list which in turn does `const {document} = this.props;` are there any guidelines?